# Preventing second click handler from firing

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add a click handler to the whole document after a button is clicked, however what I'm getting is that the second handler fires immediately when the button is clicked. The behaviour I want is that the second click would execute the new handler.

```
    $('#blah').click(function(){
            toggle();
        });


var toggle = function(){

            //event handler to close popup if clicked anywhere on screen
            $(document).on('click',offClick);


    }

    var offClick = function(event){

        if (!$(event.target).closest('.modal-dialog').length && this.stateOpen === true) {
            toggle();
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: You can use `e.stopPropagation()` or `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`